# How to fill in missing data in excel

Tags: excel

Please, Let me explain my question starting off with an example, for don't know how else to put this.

I have a set of data like this

```
Subject    Measure1
----------
Person1    1
Person1    2
Person1    3
----------
Person2    1
Person2    2
----------
Person3    2
```

And I need to fill some data so it looks like this:

```
Subject    Measure1
----------
Person1    1
Person1    2
Person1    3
----------
Person2    1
Person2    2
Person2    <null>
----------
Person3    <null>
Person3    2
Person3    <null>
```

Where null is just an empty cell, and the inserted data should keep the present records in the proper order it would be if the other rows where there (like in person 3 example)
In other words, I need to have always 3 lines per Subject even if the Measure column is empty. I cannot do this manually due to a very large amount of data that is to be treated.

How do I do this in Excel? I tried a lot of fill missing data approaches, but it works for existing cells with no data. What I need is to insert rows following a rule.

Edit: formatting

Comment: I would write some VBA code to do it. Go ahead and try it yourself and if you run into trouble come back to edit your question and include your own effort along with any error messages you have encountered.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sadly, I don't know any VBA. Any suggestions where could I begin with?

Comment: if you have Power Query, you can Pivot and then Unpivot the data http://excelunplugged.com/2014/09/30/the-pivot-option-in-power-query/. There are other ways to Pivot an Unpivot without Power Query, but it's more complicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651

Comment: @Slai, thanks, I'll try this when I get a Windows OS. I'm on a Mac and we don't have Power Query... :(

Comment: you can generate the first column with a combination of copy, Remove Duplicates, copy below x 2, and sort. Then the second column with vlookup(), row(), and mod() functions

Comment: @Slai, I got the vlookup, but didn't understand how to use row and mod with it.

I managed to distribute the data in the pivot table and got something like this:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3z4mh7m5vdxzvd/Screen%20Shot%202017-09-16%20at%2021.54.21.png?dl=0

Is it easier to go from here?

Comment: looks great. Easiest is to copy paste the person column 3 times, and then copy paste each of the 3 columns below each other (unless you can unpivot on Mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651)

Comment: Yes, I managed to unpivot, in my wife's mac that's running Office 2011... My Office 2016 doesn't seem to have a pivot table wizard! Thanks for the directions.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the directions Slai commented on, and managed to reorder my data. I had a little bit of manual work because my MS Office version wasn't compatible with the suggested tools.